# Buildrowset ampscript with descending order for single attribute in XML feed

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Is it possible to use the BuildRowset function and have a descending order for a single attribute in the feed? If we get 4 records with 4 different time stamps for each, we'd like to sort them by earliest to latest.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting XML with an XPATH is easier to do with XPATH 2.0, but SFMC only supports XPATH 1.0.

This may be an option for you: Have SFMC Support enable Script Activities for Automation Studio.  Write a script that retrieves your XML and writes it to a Data Extension.  In your email, use the [LookupOrderedRows()](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/#LookupOrderedRows) function to retrieve the data in the desired order.